# How to create with Intellij and swing interface tab like functionality?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, interface, desktop

I have a task to create a desktop app and I decided to use Swing as I have some experience with it. Also I am using Intllij and I noticed it have a form creator visual interface so I want to use it because its easier.
Samples of my interface is attached here. Its not hard but I dont know which controls to use in order to make something like this. On startup I need to have some text on the right side of the window, then on press on different button on the left to change that text with some other controls like fields labels check boxes etc. Its bit like tabs but I cannot use the JTabbedPane  because it become with too different design. Could you advice me which controls to use and how to use them in order to achieve this design ?

Here is the design:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKtT3.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I am using Intllij and I noticed it have a form creator visual interface so I want to use it because its easier.

It isn't easier as you end up spending time learning the IDE instead of learning Swing. Any code that is generated will not be maintainable if you ever need to switch to a different IDE.

Learn how to create/maintain the GUI forms manually.

> , then on press on different button on the left to change that text with some other controls like fields labels check boxes etc

Start with the standard BorderLayout for the frame. Then you create a panel with your buttons to display on the left. You create a second panel that uses a `CardLayout` in the CENTER of the BorderLayout. Then when you click a button you swap the panel that is displayed in the CENTER.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). There are sections on:

1. How to Use BorderLayout
2. How to Use CardLayout

to get your started with working examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a commercial application(rather then as a leaning experience)  consider using [JIDE Common Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm)  as the MultiplePageDialog provides the functionality you seem to be describing:

[image]

In this case a series of buttons on the left controlling a panel on the right